# My Appium code is working fine on using RemoteWebDriver but getting error if replaced by AndroidDriver

Tags: appium, remotewebdriver

This is the working code.But once replaced by AndroidDriver,it starts throwing error on running the program.Libraries has been imported successfully and able to get even AndroidDriver methods but getting error on run.

```
public class TestClass {
    WebDriver d=null;
    @BeforeMethod
    public void Start() throws MalformedURLException 
    {
        //  ConstVariables.DesiredSetting();
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities=new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setCapability("BROWSER_NAME","Android");
            capabilities.setCapability("VERSION","6.0.1"); 
            capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","ZY223JX5QN");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
            capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.aaa.bapp");
            capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.aaa.bapp.activity.SplashActivity");
            d= new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
            d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    
    }
```

Comment: Getting error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/net/URL;Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/http/HttpClient$Factory;)

Answer (score 0):

Can you pls check if the below code works for you? I have just changed the way you initialized WebDriver. Rest all code should be same.

```
AppiumDriver<WebElement> d;
..... your code .....
d = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Comment: It's has been resolved as i replaced selenium 2.4.2 jars from 3.0.1 and now its working fine.